# Docker: Layering on top of shared volume

Tags: docker, device-mapper, btrfs

I want to use a shared volume in a container but the updates to data in the shared volume cannot go to the underlying directory on the host and these updates should be discarded when the container goes away.

For example:

- Create shared directory /var/data with one file /var/data/random

  > mkdir /var/data;
  >   dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1M count=100 of=/var/data/random
- Start a container using this directory as shared volume

  > docker run -v /var/data:/data -t -i --name deb debian /bin/sh
- Inside the container modify the file

  > dd if=/dev/zero bs=4k count=1 of=/data/random conv=notrunc

Here is what I would like to happen:

1) Within the container the /var/data/random should look like 4K of zero followed by random data

2) Outside the container /var/data/random would remain unmodified

Mounting the container as read-only doesn't solve the option. Copying the data and making it part of the docker image is not a solution.

I would like to use the same layering that docker uses for the root filesystem of the container to make this work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can be archived using data containers.

Take a look at this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker kill data-test-container > /dev/null 2>&1
docker rm data-test-container  > /dev/null 2>&1
docker rmi data-test-image  > /dev/null 2>&1
docker build -t data-test-image - <<END_DOCKERFILE
FROM busybox
RUN mkdir /data && dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1K count=100 of=/data/persistent
VOLUME /data
END_DOCKERFILE

docker run -d --name=data-test-container data-test-image true
echo File checksum in image:
docker run --rm --volumes-from=data-test-container busybox md5sum /data/persistent
docker run --rm --volumes-from=data-test-container busybox dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1K count=100 of=/data/persistent
echo File checksum after change:
docker run --rm --volumes-from=data-test-container busybox md5sum /data/persistent

docker rm data-test-container
docker run -d --name=data-test-container data-test-image true

echo File checksum after restore:
docker run --rm --volumes-from=data-test-container busybox md5sum /data/persistent
```

Here is the output:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 
Step 0 : FROM busybox
 ---> 4986bf8c1536
Step 1 : RUN mkdir /data && dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1K count=100 of=/data/persistent
 ---> Running in 117d1884d448
100+0 records in
100+0 records out
 ---> ac22e944c73c
Removing intermediate container 117d1884d448
Step 2 : VOLUME /data
 ---> Running in 52cf4b446255
 ---> d7f3494b1f72
Removing intermediate container 52cf4b446255
Successfully built d7f3494b1f72
b7c7fe133479afed41f0af31df7a4535d19353bc976b25393a2c6fe68344ac6b
File checksum in image:
029ae64fe02ebfb6a3ebf0af31965826  /data/persistent
100+0 records in
100+0 records out
File checksum after change:
767260fa798a55d639de0f775e18595c  /data/persistent
data-test-container
19b9e3a5d3286c7a9bee101b1984ac033a2dd8f0bd7a6648f6c451b5e0cded32
File checksum after restore:
029ae64fe02ebfb6a3ebf0af31965826  /data/persistent
```

If you want to get live data into an image (in stead of having to build it from scratch), snapshots should be the way to go, but I haven't tried this and I've been told that there is a nasty bug in the Docker image repository server code (if you set up a local server to host the snapshots) that makes it impossible to delete snapshots. This bug may have been fixed by now, though.